# ng-deep causing issues with mat-select in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-select from angular. I have used it in 2 places.

1. AppComponent
2. ModalComponent

In order to style the options panel in mat-select I have used ng-deep as follows,

In app.component.css

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  border-top: none !important;
  min-width: 100% !important; 
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-left: 17px !important;
  margin-top: -10px !important;
}
```

This was positioned correctly until another modal element was added to the page. In this modal component, ng-deep is also been used in order to style the mat-select within the modal.
In modal.component.css

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  min-width: calc(100% + 7px) !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

So now when we click on the mat-select in the modal component and then if we click on the mat-select in app component, the position of the mat-select in the app component seems to be in a different position.
Can someone please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try to add div and put your mat panel into it and writing as .yourelement ::ng-deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this using panel class.

```
<div class="custom">
  <mat-select panelClass="select-panel"></mat-select> 
</div>
```

Then in styles.css

```
.custom .select-panel{
  min-width: calc(100% + 7px) !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The answer that you have put for you as a solution is exactly, the same answer that I had already answered before.

Answer (score 2):

ng-deep is deprecates, so you should use component without encapsulation, so:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ModalComponent {}
```

The css classes you have created should encapsulate it within a div with another class and define them this way:

app.component.css

```
.custom1 .mat-select-panel {
  border-top: none !important;
  min-width: 100% !important; 
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-left: 17px !important;
  margin-top: -10px !important;
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div class="custom1">
  <!-- here mat-select whith class .mat-select-panel -->
</div>
```

modal.component.css

```css
.custom2 .mat-select-panel {
  min-width: calc(100% + 7px) !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

modal.component.html

```html
<div class="custom2">
  <!-- here mat-select whith class .mat-select-panel -->
</div>
```

For more information see:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme

Comment: <div class="options">
      <mat-select #filterSelect [(ngModel)]="default" disableOptionCentering>
        <div class="filter-top" (click)="filterSelect.toggle()">
          <p class="status">Status</p>
          <p class="collapse">
            <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
          </p>
        </div>
        <mat-option value="Active">Active</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Inactive">Inactive</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Deleted">Deleted</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </div>

Comment: I added the mat select in a div like this, but the all the styles were broken

Comment: You can provide an example of the problem in stackblitz

Comment: I was able to fix this by using panel class property